# R Shiny rendering: object 'Output' not found

Tags: r, ggplot2, shiny, frontend, backend

This is my first experience in RShiny and I got some problems. The idea is to add two select buttons: first-one is for area of New-York, then you choose neighbourhoods. As a result -- a available on Airbnb. However this code does not work even before the graph part.

I've got a dataframe, which consists of such columns for each apartment: neighbourhood_groups (Manhattan, Bronx etc), neighbourhood (221 in 5 NYC boroughs), room_type, price and availability. Later I'd like to add more quantity graphs by ggplot2 package.

```
library(shiny)

# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
ui <- fluidPage(

    # Application title
    titlePanel("New-York City apartment offer on Airbnb "),

    # Sidebar with a slider input for number of bins 
    sidebarLayout(
        sidebarPanel(
            selectInput("area",
                        "Neighbourhood:",
                        choices = c('Manhattan', 'Brooklyn', 'Bronx', 'Queen', 'Staten Island')),
            uiOutput("special"),
            selectInput("room",
                        "Room Type:",
                        choices = unique(nyc_df$room_type)),
            radioButtons("graph",
                         "Graph type:",
                         choices = c("Area plot", "Line plot"),
                         selected = "Area plot")
        ),

        # Show a plot of the generated distribution
        mainPanel(
        )
    )
)

a <- unique(nyc_df[nyc_df$neighbourhood_group == 'Brooklyn', 6])
b <- unique(nyc_df[nyc_df$neighbourhood_group == 'Manhattan', 6])
c <- unique(nyc_df[nyc_df$neighbourhood_group == 'Queen', 6])
d <- unique(nyc_df[nyc_df$neighbourhood_group == 'Staten Island', 6])
e <- unique(nyc_df[nyc_df$neighbourhood_group == 'Bronx', 6])

output$special <- renderUI({
    switch(input$area,
            "Brooklyn" = selectInput("nhd", "Neighbourhood:",
                    choices = a),
            "Manhattan" = selectInput("nhd", "Neighbourhood:",
                    choices = b),
            "Queens" = selectInput("nhd", "Neighbourhood:",
                    choices = c), 
            "Staten Island" = selectInput("nhd", "Neighbourhood:",
                    choices = d),
            "Bronx" = selectInput("nhd", "Neighbourhood:",
                    choices = e))

})




# Define server logic required to draw a histogram
server <- function(input, output) {

    output$distPlot <- renderPlot({

        area_data <- nyc_df[nyc_df$neighbourhood_group == req(input$area), ]
        data <- area_data %>% filter(NHD == req(input$nhd),
                                     Room == req(input$room))
        barplot(data)
    })
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: The error is related to `output$special`.  It's located in your `ui`, but needs to be in the `server` along with the other `output` (also put the lines defining `a` through `e` inside `server`.  The second point to note is that I'm not seeing a reference to `output$distPlot` in your `ui` page.  Did you forget to add `plotOutput('distPlot')` within the `mainPanel(`?  Forgetting to reference it will not give you an error (since it's not called), but you're probably not going to see a plot either.  :/

Comment: oh thanks! that actually helped! now starting to edit the mainPanel part